# Subtract one hour result

Tags: sql, db2

I am pulling live data from a db2 server, I am building a Power bi report that shows by time each transaction made. There is a time difference between our server location so the result is one hour ahead. I am trying to subtract one hour from HVTIME (TIME). I can create a custom measure in Power Bi to do this but I am unable to add it to an Axis.

I have tried different SQL statements with no luck.

```
select

seri.htsern as Serial,
seri.htpart as PartNumber,
seri.htlotn as Batch,
seri.htqty as Quantity,
seri.htstkl as Bin,
seri.htbinl as Location,
serh.hvuser as ReceivedBy,
serh.hvtdat as RecievedDaten,
serh.hvtime as Time

from seri

left join serh on hvsern = htsern


where hvtdat between '2019/10/01' and current date
and hvtrnt = 'R'
and htplnt = 'GC'
```

The result I am looking for should be 10:04:53 under HVTIME (TIME).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVMXE.png)

Comment: So are you simply looking for date/time functions in db2? I would google for that. Also, as an aside, its generally not good practice to use datetime strings that are ambiguous like '10/01/2019'. I cant tell if its DMY or MDY. Best generic format is usually yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: I have googled extensively on how to subtrack one hour from the time result with no luck, I have tried different SQL statements with no luck, I know there is a difference between db2 and sql but not that much, still doesn't work.  Thank you for the note, I will put that into practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
(serh.hvtime - 1 hour) as Time
```

You may find [this article](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/fun-with-dates-and-times/) useful for date/time stuff in DB2.

Comment: And this is why you are a genius. This did the trick, Thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you for the article. I will defensively save it as a fav.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

```
SELECT seri.htsern AS Serial
    ,seri.htpart AS PartNumber
    ,seri.htlotn AS Batch
    ,seri.htqty AS Quantity
    ,seri.htstkl AS Bin
    ,seri.htbinl AS Location
    ,serh.hvuser AS ReceivedBy
    ,serh.hvtdat AS RecievedDaten
    ,(serh.hvtime - 1 hour) AS TIME
FROM seri
LEFT JOIN serh ON hvsern = htsern
WHERE hvtdat BETWEEN '2019/10/01'
        AND CURRENT DATE
    AND hvtrnt = 'R'
    AND htplnt = 'GC'
```